# Do M-Discs last for 1000 Years?

Tags: technology

The manufacturer of the [M-Disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-DISC) DVD [claims](http://www.mdisc.com/) that the data written on these discs will last for 1000 years if the discs are written to and stored correctly.

> What is worth saving forever? Thanks to M-DISC™, the permanent storage solution, you don't have to decide. This new standard of storage engraves your information into a patented rock-like layer that has been proven to last 1,000 years [...]

Is there any evidence for this?

Comment: Have you even looked at the links in the wikipedia page you linked to? The first one is called 'Final Report for Millenniata DVD Testing August 2009-October 2009', which might shed some light on how they did their testing. You'd also probably want to ask the manufacturer for their test methods and results.

Comment: @MichaelKohne: I read that report. While they may have gathered the data as required by the ECMA-397 standard, they never take the step of calculating the expected lifetime.

Comment: You might do better if your question included things like the evidence presented by the manufacturer, and what you consider wrong with that evidence.

Comment: Unless you're willing to wait for 1000 years, there isn't really a definitive answer anyway. AFAIK there are claims that accelerated aging test are unreliable.

Comment: Even if the disc is good for 1000 years, what are the chances of a (working) reader being available then? Have you seen an 8" floppy drive recently (they're still on eBay)?